# How to map java enum to postgreSQL enum for conditional select query

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot

I am using PostgreSQL and java for building the backend of an application.

In PostgreSQL, I have used an enum here.

[image]

and in java I have used enum for layer variable also.

```
     @Entity
     @Getter
     @Setter
     @Table(name = "usecase_details")
     @JsonIgnoreProperties
     public class UsecaseDetails {
     @Id
     @Column(name="id", nullable = false)
     @SequenceGenerator(name= "usecase_details_sequence", sequenceName 
     ="usecase_details_id_sequence")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = 
     "usecase_details_sequence" )
private Long id;
@Column(columnDefinition = "layer_t", nullable = false)
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
@Type(type = "com.apple.exampleportal.portal.utility.EnumTypePostgreSql")
private Layer layer;
private Long check_id;
private int usecase_id;
private String description;
private String fix_type;
private String radars;
private boolean show_usecase = true;


public UsecaseDetails(Long id, Layer layer, Long check_id, int usecase_id, String description, String fix_type, String radars, boolean show_usecase) {
    this.id = id;
    this.layer = layer;
    this.check_id = check_id;
    this.usecase_id = usecase_id;
    this.description = description;
    this.fix_type = fix_type;
    this.radars = radars;
    this.show_usecase = show_usecase;
}
// skipping getter setter for brevity
```

EnumTypePostgreSql. class is

```
   public class EnumTypePostgreSql extends EnumType {

@Override
public void nullSafeSet(
        PreparedStatement st,
        Object value,
        int index,
        SharedSessionContractImplementor session)
        throws HibernateException, SQLException {
    st.setObject(
            index,
            value != null ?
                    ((Enum) value).name() :
                    null,
            Types.OTHER
    );
}
 }
```

and my custom queries are as follows:

```
   public interface UsecaseRepository extends JpaRepository<UsecaseDetails, Long> {


@Query(value = "SELECT  description, fix_type, usecase_id, layer FROM public.usecase_details WHERE layer = :layer", nativeQuery = true)
List<UsecaseDetails> findUsecaseByLayer(Layer layer);

@Query(value = "INSERT INTO public.usecase_details(description,fix_type, usecase_id,  layer)\n"+
        "\tVALUES (?,?,?,?)", nativeQuery = true)
UsecaseDetails insertDetails(UsecaseDetails usecaseDetails);
```

The insert query is working properly but for findUsecaseByLayer , I am getting the following error.
[image]

I am unable to detect my mistake. Please help!

Answer (score 0):

There's probably something wrong with how you declare the type in `EnumTypePostgreSql`.

I also noticed this in your custom query: `WHERE layer: = ?layer` is the `:` wanted before your equal?

**The solution I use:**

Remove the `@Type` annotation from your entity column

```
@Column(columnDefinition = "layer_t", nullable = false)
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
private Layer layer;
```

Then add to your JDBC URI:

```
?stringtype=unspecified
```

This will automatically cast the string to its enum type.

Comment: Yeah By mistake, I put ': ' before  '='. I removed that and followed. what you have mentioned here. But I still get the same error.

Comment: Which JPA Interface are you calling when you get that error? Make sure there are no invisible characters in your query (remove the spaces `WHERE layer=?layer`). With my suggestions, your code should work properly.

Comment: Here is my  interface                                                                                                      public interface UsecaseRepository extends JpaRepository<UsecaseDetails, Long>.  I solved this error  by converting layer as String and cast it.        @Query(value = "SELECT id, description, radars, check_id, fix_type, usecase_id, layer, show_usecase FROM public.spectrum_usecase_details WHERE layer = CAST (:layer as layer_t)", nativeQuery = true)
    List<UsecaseDetails> findUsecaseByLayer(String layer);

Comment: You don't need the CAST in your query, the string will be cast automatically. If this is the query used, you should add it (and update) your question.

Comment: Remove @Type and add ?stringtype=unspecified to your JDBC URI. Then show the whole stacktrace of the error you get after these modifications.